# Find all html <img> tags and replaced by others?

Tags: php, html

There is a variable $result that contains the HTML page.

**For example:**

```
<p>Text</p>
<img src="http://test.com/img.png" alt="Some text">
<p>Other text</p>
```

I need this variable ($result) to make the change  tags while preserving the integrity of the page: 
**Was:**

```
<img src="http://test.com/img.png" alt="Some text">
```

where src = "original image"

Need:

```
<img src="http://test.com/loading.png" data-src="http://test.com/img.png" alt="Some text">
```

where src - image loading and data-src - the image is taken from an old src.

**How to parse html and make the necessary changes using php?**

Comment: Did you google it ? ...

Comment: [Regex](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html)?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Probably something like this will work:

```
$returnValue = preg_replace('#<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>#', '<img$1src="http://test.com/loading.png" data-source="$2"$3>', $result)
```